# Linq: How to verify dbcontext.SubmitChanges() for updates/inserts succeeded?

Tags: linq, verify, submitchanges

How do you verify that SubmitChanges() worked for inserts and updates? The method doesn't return a bool or int value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an insert fails it will throw a SqlException. I think it may do the same for failed updates.

Comment: I guess i'll just wrap the call with a try and catch

Comment: Throwing an exception on error is typically recommended over returning a boolean or affected row count. So I would recommend only catching the exception if you can do something about it (like log and rethrow).